# Sequential part of the program takes more time as process count increases

Tags: c, ubuntu, parallel-processing, mpi

I'm writing a parallel C program using MPICH. The program naturally has a sequential part and a parallel part. The parallel part seems to be working fine, however I'm having trouble with the sequential part.

In the sequential part, the program reads some values from a file and then proceeds to distribute them among the other processes. It is written as follows:

```
if (rank == 0)
{
    gettimeofday(&sequentialStartTime, NULL);

    // Read document id's and their weights into the corresponding variables
    documentCount = readDocuments(&weights, &documentIds, documentsFileName, dictionarySize);
    readQuery(&query, queryFileName, dictionarySize);

    gettimeofday(&endTime, NULL);
    timersub(&endTime, &sequentialStartTime, &resultTime);
    printf("Sequential part: %.2f ms\n", (double) resultTime.tv_sec + resultTime.tv_usec / 1000.0);

    //distribute the data to other processes
} else {
    //wait for the data and the start working
}
```

Here, `readQuery` and `readDocuments` are reading values from files, and the elapsed time is printed after they are complete. This piece of code actually works just fine. The problem arises when I try to run this with different number of processors.

I run the program with the following command

```
mpirun -np p ./main
```

where p is the processor count. I expect the sequential part to run in a certain amount of time no matter how many processors I use. For p values 1 to 4, this holds, however when I use 5 to 8 as p values, then the sequential part takes more time.

The processor I'm using is Intel® Core™ i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz × 8 and the operating system I have is Windows 8.1 64-bit. I'm running this program on Ubuntu 14.04 which runs on a virtual machine which has full access to my processor and 8 GB's of RAM.

The only reason that came to my mind is that maybe when the process count is higher than 4, the main process may share the physical core it's running on with another process, since I know that this CPU has 4 physical cores but functions as if it had 8, using the hyperthreading technology. However, when I increase p from 5 to 6 to 7 and so on, the execution time increases linearly, so that cannot be the case.

Any help or idea on this would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Edit: I realized that increasing p increases the run time no matter the value. I'm getting a linear increase in time as p increases.

Comment: I would try to know the exact binding cores-processes (https://wiki.mpich.org/mpich/index.php/Using_the_Hydra_Process_Manager#Process-core_Binding) or you may try to bind them manually and see what happens.

Comment: "linear increase in time" is not too informative. What's the slope and the intercept?:)

Comment: @AndrasDeak In the current setting, execution time is for p = 2, 70 ms, p = 3 80 ms, p = 4, 90 ms and so on.

Comment: I suspect the virtual machine is to blame. Isn't it possible that it doesn't actually utilize all 4 of your physical cores?

Comment: @AndrasDeak I thought of the same thing, however when p is greater than 8, I can clearly see the results of the physical restrictions. The VM definitely makes use of all of the cores but it might not be utilizing or using them efficiently in some way as you said.

Comment: Well you should already see the effect of hyperthreading above 4 cores (unless the blocking calls of MPI don't generate CPU load, I don't know how those are implemented). Not to mention that the virtual machine itself should eat up a considerable amount of CPU capacity. Doesn't it?

Comment: You *do* realize the SMT (hyperthreading) doesn't *actually* give you free cores, right? The logical cores share execution resources (functional units, decode, cache, TLBs). Basically, you're just over-scheduling, and the sequential part of your program is being starved.

Comment: @EOF the weird part is that there's a measurable difference even for 2-3-4 processes, on a system with 4 physical cores.

Comment: @EOF I do know that it doesn't give me free cores, however this increase in run time is more dramatic than it should be. I'm talking about a 10 ms increase in run time for each newly added core, which is huge when compared to just using one core.

Comment: @halileohalilei It happened to me a month ago, I deleted all my project(even source code itself) and recoded it and whalaaa! It worked.

Comment: @halileohalilei I tried Ersin's suggestion and it really worked. Thanks!